# Excel COUNTIF with variable criteria, then adding all results to cells above them

Tags: arrays, excel, sum, range, countif

Various formulas were used to create several columns of numbers.

The sums of column B and column C values created the values in column D.  The column B numbers are in descending order from B2 to B58.  Because those in C are not descending, some of the D values are not as well.

Sample:
    B   C   D
79.3    2.5 81.8
76.7    1.5 78.2
75.3    2.1 77.4
73.2    6.3 79.5*
66.9    1.6 68.5
65.2    0.6 65.8
64.6    1.7 66.3*
62.9    2.2 65.1

In this sample, two values in D come out bigger than the cells above them.

In column E, I would like to find all cells like this in column D where D(n+1) > D(n).  Wherever that happens, I'd like to add the adjacent C(n+1) to the entire range of D$2:D(n+1) cells.

Simply put, if D34 > D33, then I'd like to add C34 to all cells above that, in D$2:D33.  Ideas?

Comment: From a worksheet function/formula point of view, this distinctly seems like a circular reference where changing the preceding cells' result would recalculate the original formula. Isolating the cell values with a VBA macro may be the better route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it :-

```
=D2+SUM((D3:D$9>D2:D$8)*C3:C$9)
```

to be entered in E2 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> and pulled down, assuming that the original data starts in row 2.

The idea is that the sum of all the values in column C where the corresponding values in D below the current cell are out of order is added to the current value in column D.

[image]

**EDIT**

The formula will give incorrect results in the last row of column E if the last pair of numbers in column D are out of order (because it tries to compare D$9:D10 with D8:D$9 in the example). If we can assume that the data is followed by an empty row, this can be fixed easily

```
=D2+IF(D3<>"",SUM((D3:D$9>D2:D$8)*C3:C$9))
```

On the other hand, if we can only assume that D$2:D$9 is a fixed range, the formula should be

```
=D2+IF(ROWS(D$2:D2)<ROWS(D$2:D$9),SUM((D3:D$9>D2:D$8)*C3:C$9))
```

Thanks to @Dave M for pointing this out.

Comment: Hey @TomSharpe ... revisiting this formula.  Realized a shortcoming when I get to the last value.  It wants to sum against the blank cell that follows, making the final value incorrect (worth more than it should be).  I've transposed my data horizontally, and added a tiebreaker PRODUCT step involving COLUMN()... Current formula in B8:  ={SUM(GGP8+SUM((GGQ8:$GKK8>GGP8:$GKJ8)*ELG8:$EPA8),PRODUCT(COLUMN(A1),0.0000001))} ... and once I get to CW8, you'll see ={SUM(GKK8+SUM(($GKK8:GKL8>$GKJ8:GKK8)*$EPA8:EPB8),PRODUCT(COLUMN(AYF1),0.0000001))}  .. (it's going past GKK8 to GKL8 and past EPA8 to EPB8)

Comment: ... i.e. I imagine this needs some kind of IF step to prevent summing beyond the final cell.  The example from my Original Post above shows Column B in sequence (B2 will always be greater than B3, etc), which would also happen for the resulting formula we placed in Column E.  The same applies to where we are today.

Comment: OK, I'll try and have a look at it I the next couple of days

Comment: Yes, you're right! More exactly, if the last two numbers are out of order, it will incorrectly add the last column C value to the last column D value to produce the last column E value. So there has to be a way to detect if the formula is being evaluated in the last row - can you assume the next cell in column D is blank, or could you work with a fixed range ($B$2:$D$9 in the original example) ?

Comment: thanks, @TomSharpe .  I've transposed this horizontally, and currently do have data in the cells that follow each range.  If there's any way to talk directly, maybe that's quicker to discuss/show what I've done.

Comment: I'd be reluctant to give my email address out, the usual thing would be to continue in chat (link at bottom of page), but you need a rep of 20 to participate. If you can share your sheet via Google Sheets or Excel Online I'd be happy to have a look at it and might be able to add some suggestions.

Comment: I gotcha.  I didn't know about the messaging rule, for 20 rep minimum.  Are there other options to speak directly at length?  I have a bigger formula for work I'd like to discuss, but it'd take more time, and possibly an NDA. @tomsharpe